# scale on vertex not working

Tags: sculpting

im doing a tutorial, in this tutorial the guy makes a plane, press m merge at center adds skin modifier and subsurf, with that dot

he extrudes ok, fine, but when scaling or making it bigger the axis, it wont happen on my pc, in his pc it happens , but me when i press * S * nothing happens and i am following the exact step word by word, any idea?

[image]

https://workupload.com/file/NzyXXcUJxKp

[image]

Comment: pls add tutorial link, thx

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NV-qwSeXolY minute 1:14 , speed to -2  he makes it too fast

Comment: He doesn't use S at 1:14, he is sculpting

Comment: sorry its 1:19 from 1:19 to onwards

Comment: any tought?4321

Comment: he makes the body with a unique vertex, but my scale is not working for who knows reason

Comment: not working for that case * please help :(

Comment: control + a did the job, resulted he is not using commong scale but skin resize thanks everyone

Comment: I'm not sure how experienced you are in Blender, but I think in general timelapse videos are really not a suitable form of tutorial for beginners or maybe even advanced learners when tools are used that you don't know how they work (for example the _Skin_ modifier and that you cannot use S to scale the skinned vertex). Did you try to pause the video to see what exactly is going on there? I would try to do actual tutorials at first (I mean, this video is not even titled a tutorial and someone in the comments asks for a tutorial on this work). Just my recommendation, of course it's up to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an  operator specific to the *Skin* modifier, to my mind, inconsistent and poorly documented. The object in the video is a single vertex with *Skin* and *Subdivision Surface* modifiers.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> executes 'Resize Skin':

[image]

If you want a list of related operators, <kbd>F3</kbd> search: 'Skin' will fish them out. But you can't be blamed for finding it a bit of a mystery.

Answer (score 0):

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> did the job.

He is not using common scale but *Skin Resize*.